# restoring task pt_regs when returning to original function from ftrace handler

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

With a kernel module (LKM), the linux kernel `ftrace` functions allow you to set the `FTRACE_OPS_FL_SAVE_REGS` and `FTRACE_OPS_FL_IPMODIFY` flags, essentially allowing you to completely redirect any kernel function you can find the symbol address for, like this:

```
static void notrace my_ftrace_handler(unsigned long ip, unsigned long parent_ip,
        struct ftrace_ops *fops, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    regs->ip = new_addr;
}
```

Where `new_addr` is the address of the new function. The `kpatch` tool uses this, although never returns to the original function.

If at the end of the function pointed to by `new_addr` I try this:

```
task_pt_regs(current)->ip = orig_addr + MCOUNT_INSN_SIZE;
```

Some functions proceed without a problem, but most cause a segfault of the calling process.

The `ftrace` functions have built-in code to restore the current task's `pt_regs` upon return to the original function, which is why I'm able to go to my own function and have the arguments without a problem. However, at this point in the code, `ftrace` is no longer involved. How would I tell the kernel not to reset the current registers, so they can be used by the function at the new return address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this I had the thought that maybe I could read arguments directly from the `pt_regs *regs` pointer, within the ftrace handler. Turns out, you can. By not redirecting to another function, you can preserve the registers and the return address, while deciding whether you return there or somewhere else from the handler itself:

```
int donotexec(void) {
        return -EACCES;
}

static void notrace my_ftrace_handler(unsigned long ip, unsigned long parent_ip,
                    struct ftrace_ops *fops, struct pt_regs *regs) {

    struct linux_binprm *bprm = (struct linux_binprm *)regs->di;

    if (bprm->file)
            if (allowed_to_exec(bprm->file))
                    regs->ip = (unsigned long)donotexec;
}
```

This function hooks `security_bprm_check`, where `allowed_to_exec` is another function that checks the `bprm->file` which was read from the `regs->di` register.

This is arch dependant (see the kernel's `pt_regs` struct in `arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h`) and is limited to 5 function arguments.